# FlashDevelop Application not found when build

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

How do I have to configure my project to open the generated swf file in the debug flash player? When I hit f5 FlashDevelop tells me the following

INITIALIZING: Adobe Flex Compiler SHell (fcsh)
Starting new compile.
Loading configuration file D:\Programmierung\Flex\flex_sdk_3\frameworks\flex-config.xml
Loading configuration file D:\Programmierung\Flex\FlashDevelop_workspace\Test\obj\TestConfig.xml
obj\Test633795421567473000 (1009 bytes)
(fcsh)
Build succeeded
Done (0)
[Capturing traces with FDB]
Anwendung nicht gefunden (Application not found)

I hope some of you can help me with that

With kind regards

Sebastian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download [Flash Player 10 Projector content debugger](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/10/flashplayer_10_sa_debug.exe). Run it once. In FlashDevelop in "Project" > "Properties..." change "Test Movie" to "Play in external player". Hit F5.